# Game Maker - use of global variable and array in draw_text

Tags: game-maker, gml

In Game Maker, drawing the value of a variable using draw_text is something like this:

```
draw_text(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, string(global.variable))
```

Providing the variable in use is global, now with an array that stores the name of all the variables we would like, this problem occurs:

```
draw_text(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, string("global.") + string(arrayName[0]))
```

Instead of showing the same value as in the first draw_text, it now literally shows: global.variableName instead of variable value.

An example of this would be:

Input:

```
draw_text(10, 10, string("global.") + string(enemyName[0]));
```

Output:

```
global.Orc
```

When instead, say it would be health, it should say:

Output wished for:

```
10
```

Is there a way to do this without it being painful? I believe old Game Maker had these functions to play with:

```
variable_local_get
variable_local_array_get
```

But unfortunately they no longer exist.

Answer (score 1):

You can't pass a string for use it as varibale, but you can pass number for use it as index of an array. For example, instead many variables you can use one array, like:

```
enemy_name = "Orc";
enemy_health = 100;
enemy_speed = 4;
```

will be:

```
enemy[0] = "Orc";
enemy[1] = 100;
enemy[2] = 4;
```

Also you can define macros instead numbers, then it may looks like:

```
enemy[ENEMY_NAME] = "Orc";
enemy[ENEMY_HEALTH] = 100;
enemy[ENEMY_SPEED] = 4;
```

Other way is to use `ds_map` data structures, where key will be used as variable name.

```
data = ds_map_create();
data[? "name"] = "Orc";
data[? "health"] = 100;
data[? "speed"] = 4;
```

Answer (score 0):

From

> draw_text(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, string("global.") + string(arrayName[0]))

To

> draw_text(xCoordinate, yCoordinate, string(global.arrayName[0]))